# Can you help me diagnose the reason why my desktop PC randomly shuts down?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

*Please note that I don't have specialized hardware tools to run more advanced diagnostics.*

---

I've been using my desktop for a while now and suddenly it would get very choppy, applications would crash, then a blue screen of death would launch in Windows 7.

Twice, I've gotten a `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT` error in the BSOD. (It would appear, then very quickly shutdown the PC)

Now today, I've been using the computer for about 4 minutes, then I got another BSOD, this time I got the error `BAD_POOL_HEADER`.

I've shut down the machine and I won't turn it on until I figure out what's wrong. I feat it may cause hardware damage.

What could be causing this? My power source in the pc tower? My RAM is faulty?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Darth: Didn't even notice; on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you've got some hardware issues starting, either with RAM or maybe your motherboard.  Go into you machine's BIOS and run the builtin diagnostics and see what they have to say.  How to do that will depend on your PC and will be detailed in your user manual or on the manufacturer's web site.

Answer (score 2):

Hardware failures can cause essentially totally unpredictable problems in software. A kind of hardware failure that I've seen a few times is blown capacitors. Look at your motherboard, if you see fuzzy stuff coming out of the tops of any capacitors, that's a big problem. If you notice any of them are really bloated looking, that's still a problem...

Of course, it could be other hardware problems too.. But caps are easy to check..

Something else you can do is see how stable the machine is on another OS.. **Can you swap in a spare hard drive and install windows on that?** Or try running Linux from a LiveCD for a bit?

Comment: This could potentially be a bad driver as well, although that's a pretty remote possibility.  It couldn't hurt to try Driver Verifier.

Comment: I think a poorly written driver is a very distinct possibility. Especially if he's running Windows 7 on older hardware (and thus perhaps running legacy drivers).